# Multiple Line - Multiple CLOB per line SQL Loader

Tags: bash, oracle, sql-loader

I'm finding myself in a predicament.

I am parsing a logfile of multiple entries of SOAP calls. Each soap call can contain payloads of 4000+ characters preventing me to use varchar2. So I must use a CLOB)

I have to load those payloads onto a oracle DB (12g). 
I succesfully split the log into single fields and got the payloads and the header of the calls in two single files.

How do I create a CTL file that loads from an infile (that contains data for other fields) and reads CLOB files in pairs?
Ideally:

```
LOAD DATA
INFILE 'load.ldr'
BADFILE 'load.bad'
APPEND
INTO TABLE ops_payload_tracker
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '§'
TRAILING NULLCOLS
( id,
direction,
http_info,
payload CLOB(),
header CLOB(),
host_name)
```

but then I don't know, and can't find anywhere on the internet, how to do it for more than one record and how to reference that one record with two CLOBS.

Worth mentioning that it is JBOSS logs, on bash environment.

Comment: it's not the answer on your question but you can resolve this if you extract your clobs into separate files. 2 files for each record, let's say <id>_payload.txt and <id>_header.txt

Comment: I already create two separate files for payload and headers. How should I specify that the two files are there for the same ID? And then move on to the next ID and the next pair of CLOBS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. check size of varchar type in 12c. I thought it was increased to **32K**
   https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/extended-data-types-12cR1
2. see that sample [SQL Loader, CLOB, delimited fields](https://community.oracle.com/thread/992542)
3. > "I already create two separate files for payload and headers. How
   >   should I specify that the two files are there for the same ID?"

see example here:
https://oracle-base.com/articles/10g/load-lob-data-using-sql-loader

roughly:

**sample table**

```
1,one,01-JAN-2006,1_clob_header.txt,2_clob_details.txt
2,two,02-JAN-2006,2_clob_heder.txt,2_clob_details.txt
```

**ctl**

```
LOAD DATA 
INFILE 'lob_test_data.txt'
   INTO TABLE lob_tab
   FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
   (number_content    CHAR(10),
    varchar2_content  CHAR(100),
    date_content      DATE "DD-MON-YYYY" ":date_content",
    clob_filename     FILLER CHAR(100),
    clob_content      LOBFILE(clob_filename) TERMINATED BY EOF,
    blob_filename     FILLER CHAR(100),
    blob_content      LOBFILE(blob_filename) TERMINATED BY EOF)
```

Comment: The use of the FILLER clause wasn't clear. Thanks for the explanation!